# WPF: how to bind a templated custom control?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, custom-controls

I have a custom control([Seven Segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display)) made up of `line` and I have a collection(`ObservableCollection`) of it. Now, this is what I want to do:

- add a custom property to that custom control (number)
- bind that property to a textbox
- change the appearance of the custom control based on the value of property
- I want the color of each segment (black or white only) internally

Is it possible to do it in using pure WPF without code-behind?
Please ask for clarification if my question is not clear enough.

Comment: "pure WPF without code-behind" doesn't make sense. WPF is XAML and code-behind. Besides that, the question is far too broad. If you have problems with specific parts of your control, post code samples.

Comment: Agree with @Clemens, the question is too broad without some code samples. Also custom controls which DON'T inherit from UserControl, and which is meant to be consumed later, have a very rich code behind. The answer is probably: yes it is possible, but it is not the best design.

Comment: Yes, you can.  How?  Many different ways.  Also, MVVM != no codebehind.  Custom controls often need custom code to work properly.  It's entirely appropriate to place code in their codebehind.  Think about how the TextBox is designed, with all of its public properties you configure and bind to.  Do the same thing.